# Route WCF through intermediary?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I'm wondering whether it would be possible to have an intermediary node in the WCF pipeline;

For example;

I have an application that will use a plugin-host windows-service and communicate via WCF. The plugins themselves will be loaded by the host service in their own AppDomain. At present I'm designing the plugins to use serialization + remoting for communications between host-plugin.

**What I am wondering, is whether the host-service can be an intermediary and facilitate the application and plug-ins communicating directly?** i.e all three share the same interfaces and the service is basically receiving data and then forwarding it to the application. However, I imagine that extra recieve->resend is a waste so... Can I have the service alter the WCF end-points on the fly and have the plug-in and application communicate directly?

Answer (score 2):

I am not fully sure I understand your question, but the following has been helpful for our team when dealing with WCF Intermediary Routing:

In Windows Communication Foundation, each service endpoint actually has two addresses associated with it—a logical address and a physical address. The difference between these addresses is the same as the difference between "To" and "Via" in WS-Addressing. The logical address ("To") is the address that SOAP messages target. The physical address ("Via"), on the other hand, is the actual transport-specific network address that Windows Communication Foundation listens to for messages to arrive.

The following link provides comprehensive information regarding WCF intermediary routing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx

Comment: Okay Thanks I'll have a look